# SvnTask error in Ant Eclipse Plugin

Tags: eclipse, ant

I still encounter this error even if I included the svnant-1.3 jar in this path of my Eclipse plugin C:\Development\Java\eclipse\plugins
 \org.apache.ant_1.8.4.v201303080030\lib\svnant-1.3.jar

```
taskdef A class needed by class org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask cannot be found: org/tigris/
     subversion/svnclientadapter/SVNClientException using the classloader AntClassLoade
```

What else can be done for this? I checked svnant jar ant SvnTask class is there

Comment: I guess you need in addition `svnClientAdapter.jar` and a SVN client adapter/connector (e. g. SVNKit).

Comment: Check the build.xml to find the name of the classpath that's being used and try adding `<echo>${toString:classpathname}</echo>` so you can see exactly what's being included.